# Facebook Actionscript Api no Error Feedback Messages

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, apache-flex, facebook-actionscript-api

I am developing a little mobile project using [facebook-actionscript-api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/).

Things are working fine I am basically using pieces of code from example files. But i'm not receiving feedback messages or description from the fail Object passed to the callback function.

```as3
private function handlePost ( result : Object, fail : Object ) : void {
    if(result) {
        trace("POSTED");
    } else {
        trace( fail ); // returns [object Object]
        trace( fail[0] ); // returns undefined
        trace( JSON.encode(fail) ); // returns nothing ''
    }
}
```

How can I debug errors? 
Is there a bug here? I'm using the latest version (1.8.1).

Answer (score 0):

```
private function handlePost ( result : Object, fail : Object ) : void {
    if(result) {
        trace("POSTED");
    } else {        
        trace("Login Failed");  
        trace('code: '+fail.error.code); 
        trace('message: '+fail.error.message);
        trace('type: '+fail.error.type); 
    }
}
```